# My Deployed React app in github show blank page, if i cannot use any router or if i can deploy fresh build after create

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, github-pages

I'm facing the problem in few day. i have already checked the stackoverflow post and other resources but these info cannot solve my issue.

this is the packgejson code

```
"name": "fordeploping",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/fullstackfaizan/new-mm-r",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "gh-pages": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"

and this is the script code in packge.json
  "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

by making all efforts my react project is still show blank even if i deploy fresh react build after creating the react app the "react moving loge" it always show blank page
for check i have share my repo link
https://fullstackfaizan.github.io/new-mm-r/

i don't understand which kind of mistake taken by me while deploying if i run npm run deploy please analize and mention my mistake.

Comment: `homepage` should be either `./` or `https://fullstackfaizan.github.io/new-mm-r/`

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `"homepage": "./",` will fix the problem

Comment: Error: Creating Pages deployment failed
Error: HttpError: Invalid artifact url

Comment: it can say error during deployment process

Comment: Error: Error: Failed to create deployment (status: 400) with build version e0783b1e449275a0bc4b7090fd394328fb7417fd. Responded with: Invalid artifact url

Comment: Run actions/deploy-pages@v2
Artifact exchange URL: https://pipelinesghubeus7.actions.githubusercontent.com/g8cAWBMdLEKbqCaVSKKoxtKedbQPYWpqq5xexBujvF3w0VCZXf/_apis/pipelines/workflows/6275765066/artifacts?api-version=6.0-preview
Creating Pages deployment with payload:
{
 "artifact_url": "https://pipelinesghubeus7.actions.githubusercontent.com/g8cAWBMdLEKbqCaVSKKoxtKedbQPYWpqq5xexBujvF3w0VCZXf/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/1/artifacts?artifactName=github-pages&%24expand=SignedContent",
 "pages_build_version": "e0783b1e449275a0bc4b7090fd394328fb7417fd",
 "oidc_token": "***"